# AR Object disappear after covering the camera lenses or moving the camera lenses very close to an object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I found an issue in my Unity AR project. My AR object will disappear after covering the lenses or moving the camera lenses close enough to an object. Thanks

This is the video link: https://youtube.com/shorts/Sd8ia8cNDl8?feature=share

I have enabled extended tracking in Vuforia and this issue happening on my Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra so I don't think there is something to do with device specs.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. Extended tracking only works as long as the device tracker provides a reliable pose. The device tracker uses IMU and image data to compute the position of the device with respect to the world. If the camera is covered or the image does not contain enough information then the device tracker will report a LIMITED or NO_POSE status.

For more information see
https://library.vuforia.com/environments/device-tracking
and
https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/pose-status-and-status-info-unity